# c# equivalent to sql's "where value IN('a','b','c')"

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I basically need to change the row color of a Gridview depending of certain values.  Here's what I have:

```
if ((String)DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "STATUS") == "A" || (String)DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "STATUS") == "B" || (String)DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "STATUS") == "C")
{
    e.Row.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
}
```

I'm looking for a clearer (or should I say nicer) way, similar to what we have in sql, instead of having to use the || operator:

```
IF STATUS in('A','B','C')
```

Answer (score 4):

Use LINQ [`Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880(v=vs.100).aspx) like:

```
if(new[] {"A", "B", "C"}
        .Contains((String)DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "STATUS")))
```

If you want to ignore case then:

```
if (new[] {"A", "B", "C"}
    .Contains((String) DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "STATUS"),
        StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{

}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  Gotta get into it with that LINQ stuff !

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use set for this task,
build it statically if it will not change at run time
or build it dynamically:

```
var statuses = new HashSet<string>
{
    "A",
    "B",
    "C"
}
```

and check like this:

```
statuses.Contains((String)DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "STATUS"))
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve your goal is to create a temporary `List` of items and use the `Contains` method of the `List` in your conditional:

```
var yellowStatuses = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" };
var currentStatus = (String)DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "STATUS");
if (yellowStatuses.Contains(currentStatus))
    e.Row.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
```

Edit: @Habib beat me to the answer, and is cleaner too. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is isn't a optimum way of approaching this, but I think that this linq query can help you.

```
if ((new string[] {"A","B","C"}).Any(x=>x==(String)DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "STATUS")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Dictionary approach for this. The nice part is that you simply maintain it somewhere where that logic can be centralized and in one place.

```
var colorStatus = new Dictionary<string,Color>();
colorStatus["A"] = Color.Yellow;
colorStatus["B"] = Color.Yellow;
colorStatus["C"] = Color.Yellow;
```

And now later you can use this dictionary to test and then assign.

```
string status = (String)DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "STATUS");
if(colorStatus.ContainsKey(status))
{
    e.Row.BackColor = colorStatus[status];
}
```